# Why can't Net::SSH::Expect log in?

Tags: perl, ssh, expect

```
#!/opt/SPECTRUM/bin/perl -w

# This script will capture the running configuration of a
# Cisco SAN-OS device through an SSH session and print it to STDOUT.
#
# Error Codes:
#   0   = Success
#   255 = Usage error
#   254 = Invalid timeout value
#   252 = Login error
#   249 = Exec prompt not found error
#   244 = Error retrieving configuration
#   245 = Insufficient privileges
#   253 = Unexpected output
#

use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::SSH::Expect;

$ENV{'PATH'} = "/usr/bin:". $ENV{'PATH'};

### Main ###
if( $#ARGV != 4 && $#ARGV != 5 )
{
    print "Usage: capture_running.pl <device IP> <user> <pass> <enable_pass>
      <login_timeout_in_seconds> <capture_timeout_in_seconds>\n";
    print STDERR "Usage:  capture_running.pl <deviceIP> <user> <pass>
      <enable_pass> <login_timeout_in_seconds> <capture_timeout_in_seconds>\n";
    exit 255;
}
elsif( $ARGV[4] < 1 || $ARGV[4] > 600 )
{
    print "$ARGV[4] is the login timeout and must be an int between 1 and 600  seconds\n";
    print STDERR "$ARGV[4] is the login timeout and must be an int between 1 and  600 seconds\n";
    exit 254;
}
elsif( $#ARGV == 5 && ( $ARGV[5] < 1 || $ARGV[5] > 600 ) )
{
    print "$ARGV[5] is the capture timeout and must be an int between 1 and 600  seconds\n";
    print STDERR "$ARGV[5] is the capture timeout and must be an int between 1  and 600 seconds\n";
    exit 254;
}
else
{
    my $capture_timeout = $ARGV[4];
    if( $ARGV[5] )
    {
        $capture_timeout = $ARGV[5];
    }

    my $errorCode = 1;
    my @data;
    my $errorString = "\nHost $ARGV[0]:  \n";

    ($errorCode, @data) = GetConfig( $ARGV[0], $ARGV[1], $ARGV[2], $ARGV[3], $ARGV[4], $capture_timeout );

    if( $errorCode == 0 )
    {
        # Success.  The running configuration
        # content is in the data variable

        foreach ( @data ) { print "$_\n" }; # print the configuration to STDOUT
        exit 0;
    }
    else
    {
        print STDERR $errorString;

        if( $errorCode == 245 )
        {
            print STDERR join " ", @data, "\nEnsure that the device user has sufficient privileges to disable paging and view the config\n";
        }
        else
        {
            print STDERR join " ", @data, "\n";
        }

        exit $errorCode;
    }
}

exit 0;

sub GetConfig
{
    my $deviceIP=shift;
    my $user=shift;
    my $pass=shift;
    my $epass=shift;
    my $login_timeout=shift;
    my $capture_timeout=shift;
    my @config;
    my $msg;

    my $ssh = Net::SSH::Expect->new (
        host => $deviceIP,
        user => $user,
        password=> $pass,
        raw_pty => 1,
        no_terminal => 0,
        timeout => $login_timeout
    );

    my $login_output;
    eval { $login_output = $ssh->login(); };

    if( $@ )
    {
        $msg = "Login has failed. Output: $login_output";
        return( 252, $msg );
    }

    # login output should contain the right prompt characters
    if( $login_output !~ /\>\s*\z/ )
    {
        $msg = "Login has failed. Didn't see device prompt as expected.";
        $ssh->close();
        return( 252, $msg );
    }

    if( $login_output !~ /\>\s*\z/ )  # Replace '#' is the prompt character here
    {
        # we don't have the '#' prompt, means we still can't exec commands
        $msg = "Exec prompt not found.";
        $ssh->close();
        return( 249, $msg );
    }

    my $elogin = $ssh->exec("en");

    my $elogin2 = $ssh->exec($epass);

    if( $elogin2 !~ /\#\s*\z/ )  # Replace '#' is the prompt character here
    {
        $msg = "Exec prompt not found.";
        $ssh->close();
        return( 249, $msg );
    }

    # disable paging
    # different commands for different devices, if they don't
    # work then we will get messages about problems later
    # specifically the "No prompt after 'sh run'" error
    # errmsg doesn't get set when these error and if we use print
    # and getlines to read for errors it causes problems with print "sh run"
    # later.
    # $ssh->exec( "term pager 0" );
    my $paging = $ssh->exec( "term pager 0" );
    if ( $paging =~  /\s?%\s/ )
    {
        $msg = "Unable to set terminal size to 0 - Insufficient privileges";
        $ssh->close();
        return( 245, $msg);
    }

    $ssh->send( "sh run" );
    $ssh->timeout( $capture_timeout );
    $ssh->peek(0);

    while( my $line = $ssh->read_line() )
    {
        # get configuration content

        if( $line !~ /sh run|Building configuration|Current configuration|^\s*$/ )
        {
            push @config, $line;
        }
    }

    if( @config <= 0 )
    {
        $msg = "No data retrieved, the capture timeout may be too low.";
        $ssh->close();
        return( 244, $msg );
    }

    if( scalar grep { $_ =~ /^%/ } @config )
    {
        # Ensure show running actually returned the config and not an error
        # message containing '%'
        return( 245, @config );
    }

    return( 0, @config ); # everything was okay, return the captured data
}
```

Line 112:

```
if( $@ )
{
    $msg = "Login has failed. Output: $login_output";
    return( 252, $msg );
}
```

The $msg returned is:   Login has failed. Output: . 
Can anyone help me regarding this issue, fairly new to Perl. I am trying to get a backup of the config for a Cisco ASA device.

I have tried to use chomp, but couldn't get it working. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Removing excessive spaces

Comment: The error message means `$login_output` is undefined. The fact that you failed to login explains why.

Answer (score 1):

You have this bit of code that produces your error message:

```
eval { $login_output = $ssh->login(); };

if( $@ )
{
    $msg = "Login has failed. Output: $login_output";
    return( 252, $msg );
}
```

The `$@` is the error from the `eval`. If something went wrong with `$ssh->login` then `$login_output` would be empty.

Try this instead so you see what's in `$@`. That probably has the clue you need to continue:

```
eval { $login_output = $ssh->login(); };

if( $@ )
{
    $msg = "Login has failed.\nError: $@\nOutput: $login_output";
    return( 252, $msg );
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  

Error: SSHProcessError The ssh process was terminated.  

My credentials work, not sure why login fails. 
Reading more on NET::SSH::Expect

Comment: According to the docs that's a failure before you even had a chance to get to the network. You weren't able to create the ssh process. Since you mess with PATH at the top of the program I'd start by investigating that. I suspect that it can't find the ssh binary.

Comment: Issue fixed. The issue all this time was due to RSA keys. Removed old record from known_hosts file and established ssh connection again. Works fine :) Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to add this into your ~/.ssh/config

```
Host your_server
    user your_login
    port 22
    UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

Or the command : `ssh-keygen -R server_ip_address`

In order to avoid that the RSA host key has just been changed

Of course be aware from the man in the middle attack.